# Prove that $\;A\cdot\text{adj}(A + B)\cdot B = B\cdot\text{adj}(A +B)\cdot A$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\;A,B\;$ be $\;n\times n\;$ matrices in $F.$

Prove that $\;A\cdot\text{adj}(A + B)\cdot B = B\cdot\text{adj}(A + B)\cdot A$

**Hint :** Start with the identity $\;C\cdot\text{adj}(C) =\det(C)\cdot I$.

In for $\;C\;$ being an $\;n\times n\;$ matrix in $F.$

I've been able to find that $\;C\cdot\text{adj}(C)=\text{adj}(C)\cdot C=\det(C)\cdot I\;,\;$ but I can't figure out where to go from here because we have $\text{ adj}(A + B)\;$ and not $\text{ adj}(A)\;$ or $\text{ adj}(B)\;.$

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $A = (A+B) - B$

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: @Exodd, thank you, I have it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\;A,B\;$ be $\;n\times n\;$ matrices in $F.$

Prove that $\;A\cdot\text{adj}(A+B)\cdot B=B\cdot\text{adj}(A+B)\cdot A\;.$

**Proof :**

$\;A\cdot\text{adj}(A+B)\cdot B=$

$=A\cdot\text{adj}(A+B)\cdot\big[(A+B)-A\big]=$

$=A\cdot\text{adj}(A+B)\cdot(A+B)-A\cdot\text{adj}(A+B)\cdot A=$

$=A\cdot\big(\det(A+B)\cdot I\big)-A\cdot\text{adj}(A+B)\cdot A=$

$=\big(\det(A+B)\cdot I\big)\cdot A-A\cdot\text{adj}(A+B)\cdot A=$

$=(A+B)\cdot\text{adj}(A+B)\cdot A-A\cdot\text{adj}(A+B)\cdot A=$

$=\big[(A+B)-A\big]\cdot\text{adj}(A+B)\cdot A=$

$=B\cdot\text{adj}(A+B)\cdot A\;\;,$

hence

$\;A\cdot\text{adj}(A+B)\cdot B=B\cdot\text{adj}(A+B)\cdot A\;.$